# Save a running cmd output to a txt file with a composed name

Tags: python, python-2.7, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to create a log file that run's as a tail log in cmd.
So I need to save the output only when it's done(User hit enter), I can't figure out how to do that..

this is my code

```
MS_log = the user's input

URL_logs = 'cf logs ' + MS_Log  +' >'+ MS_Log  + 'LOG.txt'
os.system(URL_log)
```

The problem is that it's saves the current logs and does not allow my to tail..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing writing to the log file and reading from it.

First, write what you want to a file:

```
# open the file in 'a' ("append") mode to add to it after its end
with open('LOG.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(MS_Log)
```

Then, read the log file in any way you want, e.g. using the `tail` command. Note that reading would not be from inside the same script!

Answer (score 0):

the better way to write log in file with python is to use [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) module and you can also specify your file like this :

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to use python [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), which can log to multiple places at once -- both to file and to stdout.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('/path/to/file')
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

logger.warning('This will be written to file and to stdout')
```

By default, the logger only logs messages that are `warning` and above.  You can set the level lower to view other messages.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug('A debug message')
```

Answer (score 0):

cf CLI supports a path to file with env var CF_TRACE.

From `cf help`:
   CF_TRACE=path/to/trace.log         Append API request diagnostics to a log file

Caution, this will fill up your disk:

put the following in .bash_profile
`export    CF_TRACE=path/to/trace.log`

In another shell, `tail -f path/to/trace.log`

Now you can run commands and see the trace at the same time.